# Getting errors in my appdelegate when I make my masterview declared it as globally

Tags: objective-c

Here I am fighting with a problem couple of hours.

My problem is

Here is my code in appdelegate didFinishLaunching method.

```
#import "CorkItAppDelegate.h"


@implementation CorkItAppDelegate

@synthesize   window,isPicker,isFirstTime,winTyp,winTypId,wineCatName,wineRegName,theViewController,catId,regId,facebookObject,isGetWineName,getNewWineName,isNewWine,getNewWineReg,isNewReg,wineDetPk,currentLocation,internetConnectionStatus;
static NSString* mapCurrentLocationUrlArg = @"http://maps.google.com/maps?q=%s@";

- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication *)application
 {    

   // Override point for customization after application launch
    //facebookObject=[[FacebookMyLib alloc]init];
 [self createEditableCopyOfDatabaseIfNeeded];
 [self initializeDataStructures];

 [MyCLController sharedInstance].delegate = self;
 [[MyCLController sharedInstance].locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
 isGetWineName = NO;
 facebookObject = [[FacebookMyLib alloc] init];
 theViewController = [[[MasterViewController alloc] init]autorelease];
 UINavigationController* controller = [[UINavigationController alloc]     initWithRootViewController:theViewController];
 controller.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlackOpaque;
 [window addSubview:controller.view];
 [window makeKeyAndVisible];

}
```

here in this code I declared the MasterView controller globally in .h class. and it written property and synthesize for that.
But when I run the build I am getting two errors at #import "MasterViewController.h" like

```
error:expected specifier-qualifier-list before 'MasterViewController.h'.
```

I got two errores they are at:
In my MasterViewController.m
the errors are genereated at #import"MasterViewController.h"

```
#import "MasterViewController.h"
//here I am getting 2 error:expected specifier-qualifier-list before 'MasterViewController.h'.

#import "CorkItAppDelegate.h"
#import"InfoViewController.h"

@implementation MasterViewController
```

And the code in CorkItAppDelegate.h is:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <sqlite3.h>
#import "wineDetails.h"
#import "wineTypes.h"
#import "WineCategoriesList.h"
#import "MyCLController.h";
#import "Reachability.h";
#import "WineRegion.h"
#import "EventsList.h"
#import"FBConnect/FBConnect.h"
#import"FacebookMyLib.h"
#import "MasterViewController.h"

@interface CorkItAppDelegate : NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate,MyCLControllerDelegate> {

    MasterViewController* theViewController ;
    UIWindow *window;
    sqlite3 *database;
    NSMutableArray* masterViewList;
}
@property(nonatomic,retain)MasterViewController* theViewController ;

@end
```

can anyone suggest me how to get rid of this.

Anyone's help will be much Appreciated.

Thank you,
Monish.

Comment: If you can, please post the contents of CorkItAppDelegate.h also.

Comment: I don't see any issue with the apple posted code. The only other place I can think there might be an error is MasterViewController.h.

Comment: Also, I would suggest removing the CorkItAppDelegate.m code since it is not where the errors appear and is not included by any of the files were the error appears.

Comment: Ok Thanks for spending valuable time for this issue.

Comment: no problem. I can't sleep anyways. :)

Answer (score 0):

Remove all the headers except the sdk headers like

```
remove:
#import "wineDetails.h"
#import "wineTypes.h"
#import "WineCategoriesList.h"
#import "MyCLController.h";
#import "Reachability.h";
#import "WineRegion.h"
#import "EventsList.h"
#import"FacebookMyLib.h"
#import "MasterViewController.h"

Don't remove :
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <sqlite3.h>
#import"FBConnect/FBConnect.h"
```

Hopes this helps